# Create Object of type given by String

Tags: java, class, object

If I have a class

```
class Foo {
    int t;
}
```

and I have a string, `String s = "Foo";`, would it be possible to create an object of the type defined by the field `s`? So something like `Foo f = new s();`, or something like that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You _can_, but if you're asking us, then you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem. Please explain what goal you have.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have a very long switch statement where I'm basically checking if my input matches a string, and then making an object if it does. Each class has the same name as the string i'm matching so i thought if I could do this it would be a lot shorter and hopefully more readable

Comment: Why are you "making an object", generically? Do these objects need input? If not, how do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `s` is the name of your variable, so you cannot instantiate it using `s()`. If you wanted to do something like that then you would need a class called "s". You can't create an instance of a variable name.